# Deploying Django Application to Railway. Error with requirements.txt

Tags: django, deployment, railway

I am trying to deploy a simple django application to Railway, but keep running into this issue.

```
5.606 ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 5.0 Requires-Python >=3.10; 5.0.1 Requires-Python >=3.10; 5.0a1 Requires-Python >=3.10; 5.0b1 Requires-Python >=3.10; 5.0rc1 Requires-Python >=3.10

5.606 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==5.0 (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7 ... 4.2.9)

5.606 ERROR: No matching distribution found for Django==5.0

...

ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c python -m venv --copies /opt/venv && . /opt/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Error: Docker build failed
```

My requirements.txt file is:

```
asgiref==3.7.2
crispy-bootstrap4==2023.1
Django==5.0
django-crispy-forms==2.1
gunicorn==21.2.0
packaging==23.2
Pillow==10.1.0
pytz==2023.3.post1
sqlparse==0.4.4
```

My Procfile is:

```
web: gunicorn 'django_net.wsgi' --log-file -
```

my runtime.txt file is:

```
python-3.12.1
```

I am very new to deploying so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

I am very new to deploying so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.render.com/python-version